# NSURLSessionDataTask does not work on macOS, "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."

Tags: macos, nsurlsessiondatatask

Why does `dataTaskWithURL` work on iOS, but not on macOS?

The error message is:

> Client-Error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

My routine is as follows:

```
- (void)loadHTML {
    NSString *urlString = @"https://morph.zone/modules/newbb_plus/viewtopic.php?topic_id=12630&forum=10";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Client-Error:%@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            if (httpResponse.statusCode < 200 || httpResponse.statusCode > 299) {
                NSLog(@"Server-Error:%ld",httpResponse.statusCode);
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Data downloaded");
            }
        }
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.
I have overlooked that.
It is working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For macOS targets, you must explicitly enable “Outbound Connections (Client)” on the “Capabilities” tab:

[image: capabilities]

Until you do that, all outbound connections will fail with [`NSURLErrorCannotFindHost`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorcannotfindhost) error.